# What will the following tcl code do?

Tags: if-statement, try-catch, tcl

I have the following line:

```
if {[catch {exec fgrep E- $log_file} errors]} {
    set errors ""
}
```

What does this do?

- Does the `catch` command puts all the lines found by `fgrep` in the log file into `errors`?
- Will it put there only errors thrown by `fgrep`, for example if the file doesn't exist?
- When will the `if` be taken, and when it won't be taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's deconstruct your code from the inside out.

```
exec fgrep E- $log_file
```

This runs `fgrep E-` against the file whose name is stored in the variable `log_file`. It produces a Tcl error if there is a syntactic problem with the `exec` (there isn't, thankfully), a syntactic problem with the `fgrep` program (looks OK to me), if `$log_file` doesn't exist, or if there were no matches. If there were no errors, it returns the output of the grepping, warts and all.

```
catch {exec fgrep E- $log_file} errors
```

This runs the code from above in an environment which traps errors, and returns whether an error occurred (formally, it returns 0 when there was no error, 1 when there was an error, and other codes for other less-common types of exceptional return which don't happen in this case). The normal result of the `exec` is stored in the `errors` variable if no error happened, and the error message is stored in `errors` if there *was* an error. Note that it's possible to distinguish between the types of errors through the global `errorCode` variable, but you don't do that (and it's often not necessary).

```
if {[catch {exec fgrep E- $log_file} errors]} {
    set errors ""
}
```

This uses the result of the `catch` above as a boolean: if an error happened, it evaluates the body (which sets the `errors` variable to the empty string), and otherwise it does nothing extra.

### Summary

*Overall*, your code sets `errors` to the newline-separated lines found in the file in `log_file`, and sets `errors` to the empty string otherwise.

Comment: +1 excellent answer. I prefer to be more explicit about handling [the status returned by `catch`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/catch.htm) -- the return value is not strictly a boolean value, it is a status code: `if {[catch {...} errors] != 0} { ...`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. If the command `exec fgrep E- $log_file` returns any errors, they will be caught and the variable `errors` will be assigned the error message. In this case it is the results of the `exec` command that is being caught. Looking at the [manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm) you can see the particularities of how exec returns an error. Your code example immediately over-writes the `errors` variable. I should add that `errors` is a slightly misleading choice of variable name - `results` would be better, as the variable gets set whether or not an error occurs.

So the `if` will be taken if the `catch` finds an error. I couldn't comment on the question regarding fgrep not finding a file. It's not clear to me if that is an error or a normal situation.